# Combinatorics Problem at a theater

Tags: combinatorics

At a movie theatre, $m+n$ people stand in line to buy tickets. The ticket price is \$5. Suppose $m\geq n$, and $m$ of those people only has \$5 bills and the remaining $n$ people only has \$10 bills. At the beginning, no change is available at the ticket counter. It is desirable to arrange the order of these $m+n$ people in the line so that nobody needs to wait for change when buying the ticket, or exchange bills among each other. In how many ways can this be done?

Sorry for the lack of mathjax and the simplicity of this problem because I am just learning combinatorics.

Comment: Dollar signs are used to delimit LaTeX (MathJax) markup; if you want a dollar sign to display, you need to escape it with a backslash. (It looks like someone is already editing your post to fix this)

Comment: See this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990747/cashier-has-no-change-catalan-numbers-probability-question/992241

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: See also this *very* similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22999.

Answer (score 1):

For every person with with a \$10 bill we need another person with a \$5 bill that comes first. Let $k=1,2,3,\ldots,m+n$ denote the position in the queue where $k=1$. Let $n_k$ be the total number of people with \$10 dollar bills in the positions $1,2,3,...,k$ and $m_k$ be the number of people with \$5 dollar bills in these positions.

Then we need to have $m_k \geq n_k$ for every $k$ (lets call this fact (a)).

We obviously have $m_k \geq m_{k-1}$ and similarly $n_k \geq n_{k-1}$ and also $n_{m+n} = n$ and $m_{m+n} = m$. Also $m_k - m_{k-1} \leq 1$ and $n_k - n_{k-1} \leq 1$ (lets call this (c)).

We can solve this by using dynamic programming. Lets draw this as a table of states: The $k$-th antidiagonal (going from top right to bottom left, consitsting of all the states $s_{i,j}$ with $i+j=k$) shows the possible states in the $k$-th position. The column index represents $m_k$ and the the row index $m_k$. For the visualization as table I use $n=2$ and $m=3$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}n_k \setminus m_k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 & s_{0,0} & s_{0,1} & \cdots & \\ \hline
1 & s_{1,0} & \ddots & & \\ \hline
2 & \vdots & & & \end{array}$$

Now each of the ways to arrange the queue represents a path through this from $s_{0,0}$ to $s_{n,m}$ where we are just allowed to go right or down. Due to (a) we know all subdiagonal states are not allowed

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}n_k \setminus m_k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 &  &  &  & \\ \hline
1 & \times &  & & \\ \hline
2 & \times & \times & & \end{array}$$

So now let $s_{i,j}$ count the number of ways to get to $s_{i,j}$ we have $s_{0,0} = 1$ and we are looking for $s_{n,m}$. If $i=j$ then we can just have com from the top so $s_{k,k} = s_{k-1,k}$ for all $k$, if $i=0$ we can just come from the left so $s_{0,j}=1$ for all $j$. So to compute each $s_{i,j}$ we just have to add the numbers from top and left (where possible) so if $i<j$ and $i \neq 0$ we have $s_{i,j} = s_{i-1,j} + s_{i,j-1}$, and the grid will look like so:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}n_k \setminus m_k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\ \hline
1 & \times & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
2 & \times & \times & 2 & 5\end{array}$$

This means to find $s_{n,m}$ you just have to evaluate the recursion given in the paragraph above.